# Program not running properly when run in terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, c++

I am running C++ programs using the Gnome terminal emulator in Ubuntu 10.04. The program has a number of steps and I get the program to print something to terminal after every one to tell me how far it's got. At the end it then prints to file.

I often have the following two problems:

The program freezes when I click on somewhere other than the terminal or minimize it. This is evident by the fact that it stops printing to screen. The program can be easily unfrozen by simply double-clicking on the terminal.

The terminal goes blank, displaying nothing but the cursor. This flickers, probably when something new is supposed to be printed to screen. The program seems to still be running, since it prints to file at the end. But sometimes the results it prints make no sense.

Has anyone seen anything like this before, and know what kind of issues cause it?

Comment: Do you use C-style printf statements or C++ style std::cout<< operations?

Comment: It's the latter that I use

Comment: My guess is you're sending a dangling pointer to stdout. Run the program while redirecting its output to file (append `>output` to the command line) and examine what actually gets written. Use the `od` utility to look at the possibly binary data in the file.

Comment: It's difficult to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem without seeing the source code.